# Command to know if file is created

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage

I have a disk of 2TB and looking for command to know when, where, current size and by whom this file was created. Linux commands like 'Find' or 'ls' is working but these commands are slow for storage drive more than 2TB. Any suggestion to get information immediately when file is modified/created.

Comment: The size of the disk have *no* influence on how long `ls` takes, that only reads the current directory. The time `find` uses does increase when the amount of data on the disk increases (and that tends to follow the disk size, but it doesn't have to, so that claim is also wrong). And they aren't of much use if you want information immediately, but try to describe your goal more clearly.

Comment: Use [inotify](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki)

Comment: @IporSircer Watching every single directory in a large tree?

Comment: inotify is not for resursive.